# Best Practice for fields in the model

Tags: model-view-controller, model, controller, field

I was wondering if there is a best practice to set the fields a model will retrieve. Between this 2 different approaches (pseudo-code):

1. Define the values in the controller and send them to model.

   ```
   Controller::get()
   {
       $fields = ['id_user', 'name', 'etc'];
       Model::get_by_email($email, $fields);
   }

   Model::get_by_email($email, array $fields)
   {
       return fetch('SELECT $fields FROM user');
   }
   ```
2. The model method defines the fields to retrieve.

   ```
   Controller::get()
   {
       Model::get_by_email($email);
   }

   Model::get_by_email($email)
   {
       $fields = [self::ID_USER, self::NAME, self::ETC);
       return fetch('SELECT $fields FROM user');
   }
   ```

You get different pros an cons on each approach. What do you think?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should have been in http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

In most of the applications I've seen, none of the approach was used, it was something like this:

```
Controller::get()
{
    Model::get_by_email($email);
}

Model::get_by_email($email)
{
    return fetch('SELECT user, name, etc FROM user where email=$email');
}
```

So the selected fields are hardcoded in the query. Either it retrieves every column in the table (some kind of "generic" request), or each service has a specific request which retrieves just what it needs.

Depending on the stack you are using, you will also have a "Service" layer between controllers and the model (in Java apps, for example). IMO controllers should not ask for what they want, they just assume that services/model give them what they need. As it is some form of "client" for the underlying layer, it should not ask any requirement but rather use what is provided.

Your second approach is quite similar to what I describe, but to me the `$fields` array seems unnecessary, because as you describe it, its content is static.

Comment: That is also approach #2, it doesn't mather if you define the fields in a variable, hardcoded or ORM. The idea is to see if is better to send this field in the controller or rather define them in the model. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. The array was just quick pseudo-code, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches are wrong, because in both cases you are exposing either domain logic or storage logic to the presentation layer.

Also, where the hell did you read an MVC description that require controller to retrieve data? Controllers only responsibility is to decide, how user input is passed to the model layer (and, in few cases - to the current view).

Comment: In approach 2 the controller is just passing the input (email) to the model. Basically you said why this is all wrong but didn't mention any positive feedback on which other approach should be used, that's a great answer...